# Load remote server image in UIScrollView with NSOperatoinQueue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, nsoperationqueue, nscache

I want to load some "image" (In remote server) in a `UIScrollView` with `NSOperatoinQueue`. Because If I load it with normal `NSURL`, `NSData` or with `NSMutableURLRequest` it takes too much time to load for all the images. After that I show those images in `UIButton`. Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self startAnimation:nil];

    self.imageDownloadingQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    self.imageDownloadingQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 4; // many servers limit how many concurrent requests they'll accept from a device, so make sure to set this accordingly
    self.imageCache = [[NSCache alloc] init];

    [self performSelector:@selector(loadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}


-(void) loadData
{
    adParser = [[AdParser alloc] loadXMLByURL:getXMLURL];
    adsListArray = [adParser ads];
    displayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (AdInfo *adInfo1 in adsListArray)
    {
        AdInfo *adInfo2 = [[AdInfo alloc] init];
        [adInfo2 setBannerIconURL:adInfo1.bannerIconURL];
        [adInfo2 setBannerIconLink:adInfo1.bannerIconLink];
        [displayArray addObject:adInfo2];
    }
    [self loadScrollView];
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}


-(void) loadScrollView
{
    [self.scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake([displayArray count] * ScrollerWidth, ScrollerHight)];

    for (int i = 0; i < [displayArray count]; i++)
    {
        adButtonOutLet = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*320, 0, ButtonWidth, ButtonHight)];
        currentAd = [displayArray objectAtIndex:i];

        NSString *imageUrlString = [currentAd bannerIconURL];
        UIImage *cachedImage = [self.imageCache objectForKey:imageUrlString];
        if (cachedImage)
        {
            [adButtonOutLet setImage:cachedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.imageDownloadingQueue addOperationWithBlock:^
             {
                 NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString]];
                 UIImage *image    = nil;
                 image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                 // add the image to your cache
                 [self.imageCache setObject:image forKey:imageUrlString];
                 // finally, update the user interface in the main queue
                 [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^
                  {
                      [adButtonOutLet setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                  }];
             }];
        }

        adButtonOutLet.userInteractionEnabled= YES;
        [adButtonOutLet setTag:i];
        [adButtonOutLet addTarget:self action:@selector(goToURL:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self.scrollView addSubview:adButtonOutLet];
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the above code? There is no problem of parsing or retrieving data from Remote server. I check it by `NSLog`. I think the `NSOperationQueue` have some problem, which I can't manage properly. Thanks in advance. If you needed more information, I will attach here.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Your adButtonOutLet is a class variable? It would mean that you only have 1 button initialised and on your UIScrollView

Comment: @JasperPol Thanks for commenting. Yes, I declare it as a property `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *adButtonOutLet;`, but if that so, when I run the code, there should be at least one button showing in the simulator, isn't it? But nothing is there. Besides, In regular way using `NSURL` & `NSData` all button showing correctly in `scrollView`. Then whats wrong with it? :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your problem or your solution, its hard to tell without testing myself.

Taken from [RayWenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues)

> addOperationWithBlock: if you have a simple operation that does not
>   need to be subclassed, you can create an operation using the block
>   API. If you want to reference any object from outside in the block,
>   remember that you should pass in a weak reference. Also, if you want
>   to do something that is related to the UI in the block, you must do it
>   on the main thread:

```
// Create a weak reference
__weak MyViewController *weakSelf = self;

// Add an operation as a block to a queue
[myQueue addOperationWithBlock: ^ {

    NSURL *aURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.somewhere.com/image.png"];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:aURL options:nil error:&error];
    UIImage *image = nil;
    If (data)
        image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    // Update UI on the main thread.
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock: ^ {
        weakSelf.imageView.image = image;
    }];

}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. And yes, it's absolutely working if I take an Extra `UIImageView` and load image in there, creating a weak reference of `MyViewController`( `__weak MyViewController *weakSelf = self;`). But the thing is, here I want to load all of my image in `UIButton` as subView and then Button are added in `scrollView` as `subView`. In that case what is good about creating a weak reference of `MyViewController`? When I take the final `image` as input of my `UIButton` it not showing the images at all. :(

Comment: I think if you would not use a class iVar but just alloc and init buttons inside your loop you would not have to use a weak reference to your UIViewController. I don't really see the point anyway in having a class iVar for that button.